# create a form that input user id

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a new table i called it request , where i have a form with fname, lname, amount, cedula, my query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO request (fname, lname, amount, cedula ) VALUES ('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[amount]','$_POST[cedula]')";
```

now it work,s and insert all data, but i need it to insert user id when logged in(not session id)or maybe I'm wrong user id and session id ain't the same right?, because i need to do an echo to the amount of submitted loans and amount column value by user, I'm using user-spice , now when user is logged in it already has a user id, i just don't know how to insert this id value, then eventually create another query to fetch by id. which is the best approach to get this done?

Comment: you want to use UPDATE if you want to track if a user is logged in.

Comment: Are you creating user ids? with autoincrement, manually or something?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. Never put `$_GET` or `$_POST` data directly in a query.

Comment: user id is already created im using user spice, user register framework, but i need to add another form which i did but i need it to  insert user id as well